# PowerShell To Retreive HTML from an open tab

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I am trying to retrieve links from a dynamic JavaScript-rendered web page using PowerShell.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#  Create IE object and load URL
$ie = New-Object -comobject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url)

 # Wait for the page to load 

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true -Or $ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {Start-Sleep 2}

$Doc = $ie.Document
$divs = $Doc.getElementsByTagName('a')

foreach ($div in $divs){
write-host $div['id'].value
write-host $div['tagName'].value
write-host $div['parentElement'].value
write-host $div['style'].value
write-host $div['document'].value
write-host $div['sourceIndex'].value
write-host $div['offsetLeft'].value
write-host $div['offsetTop'].value
write-host $div['offsetWidth'].value
write-host $div['offsetHeight'].value
write-host $div['offsetParent'].value
write-host $div['innerHTML'].value
write-host $div['innerText'].value
write-host $div['outerHTML'].value
write-host $div['outerText'].value
write-host $div['parentTextEdit'].value
}
```

However, all of the output is blank lines.

(FYI - if I output just the `$div`, then I get `System.__ComObject`

Can anyone explain what I need to do to get the information?

Thank you.

Comment: for starter in that loop, current item it's not `$divs` but `$div`

Comment: I think most of those properties are objects with other properties. You probably may have to navigate to the bit of data you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would change the names of `$divs` to `$tags` and use `$tag` rather then `$div` in the foreach loop, because you are not really looking for divs, but `<a>` tags.

Each $tag has a `getAttribute` method you should use instead of `$tag['attribName'].value`.

Your code could then look like this

```
$ie = New-Object -comobject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url)

 # Wait for the page to load 

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true -Or $ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {Start-Sleep 2}

$Doc = $ie.Document
$tags = $Doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

foreach ($tag in $tags){
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("id")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("tagName")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("parentElement")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("style")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("document")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("sourceIndex")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("offsetLeft")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("offsetTop")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("offsetWidth")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("offsetHeight")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("offsetParent")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("innerHTML")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("innerText")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("outerHTML")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("outerText")
    Write-Host $tag.getAttribute("parentTextEdit")
}
```

Also, when finished you should cleanup the COM object you have created:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

**Edit**

to make better output i suggest this:

```
$Doc = $ie.Document
$tags = $Doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
#$tags = $doc.all.tags("a")

$attribs = @("id", "tagName", "parentElement", "style", "document", "sourceIndex", 
             "offsetLeft", "offsetTop", "offsetWidth", "offsetHeight", "offsetParent", 
             "innerHTML", "innerText", "outerHTML", "outerText", "parentTextEdit")

foreach ($tag in $tags){
    $attribs | ForEach-Object {
       @{ $_ = $tag.getAttribute($_) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, @Theo; Again, the only output I get is lines of no values (blank lines).

Comment: Ok. you could try `$tags = $doc.all.tags("a")` instead  of `$tags = $Doc.getElementsByTagName("a")` although i think it would make no difference.

Perhaps the page you reference uses an iframe, so you might be looking in the wrong document for the tags.. In that case `$ie.document.GetElementById("IFrameName").document.GetElementsByTagName("a")` would do it.

Comment: Really appreciate this @Theo! :) In your edited code, the output displays the columns for the attributes, and a column for the value - but the value is still blank for each attribute. Any ideas?

Comment: Examine the page in the url you are probing. I really do think it uses an iFrame to display the content you are trying to parse. In that case, get the ID of that iFrame and put that in here `$ie.document.GetElementById("IFrameName").contentwindow.document.GetElementsByTagName("a")`.  P.S. some attributes will still show up as `System.__ComObject` because not everything about a tag is a string..

Comment: Back-track - firewalls issues too! All working, as per your code above. Thank you very much indeed!